# User used by Java Client API to access Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, hadoop2

I am learning Hbase.I want to know a Java Client will communicate with Hbase data ? I can see there are config ,HConnectionManager Classes to communicate with Hbase.I am curios to understand which userID does the client uses for this communication.

For Example :
Say, I am running a hbaseTest.jar (i.e. My Java Client Jar file) from my local. My user ID : learner. and my /apps/data  for hbase has the owner hbase.

What is the user Id used by my Java Client?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to get the user:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User;

User u = User.getCurrent();
System.out.println(u.getName());
```

To change the use which you want to access Hbase, you can set environment variable for ("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "yourNewUser"). In eclipse, you can set in Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM arguments -> **-DHADOOP_USER_NAME=pedapna**